# how to create responsive webcam cards that grows and shrinks following the number of people?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Django so I'm a bit off on the front-end and i was hoping i can find help

I want to create a video chat website where a bunch of people can join the chat room, but I'm stuck with the UI.

I'm looking to make the first cam (mine) big until someone else joins and they get shrunk to the same size.

Also, I'd like the size of everything to be the height of the page, The size of the webcam shrinks and not the other way around.

I searched everywhere for a template but I haven't found
I couldn't even deliver my question to google

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple first just collect the no. of people and using python print this logic in between of the page

first collect the no. of people and store in a variable suppose `a`
after this if `a` updates by +1 then print `div` with height `(height of the container in which webcam cards are there)px / a` and width `(width of the container in which webcam cards are there)px / a` this will change the size of the div.

I hope you find it correct. I do not know Django but logics are same in every language. So, I have just told you the logic and now you can frame your code :)